# python's inspect.stack not returning filename with jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, filenames

For traceability purposes, I want to save the filename of the caller of a custom library's function as metadata when a data file is created from that library.

My folder structure simplified is something like this :

```
root
|
|___.  some_folder
|   |___   jupyter_notebook.ipynb
|   |___   control_test.py
|
|___.  __packages__
    |___   __init__.py
    |___   a_worker_module.py
    |___   caller_module.py
```

The function `get_outside_caller_info` below is located in my `caller_module.py` and uses the module `inspect` and the fact that all my library scripts are inside a folder named `__packages__` while the `jupyter_notebook.ipynb` or actively developped other python files like  `control_test.py` can be somewhere else, here , in `some_folder`.
To ensure the caller name will be something usefull for me, I just have to get up the inspect stack and stop once the caller's filename appears to not be inside the `__packages__` folder.

The code in the library for the filename / object getter is like this :

```py
import inspect, os
def get_outside_caller_info():
    """
    Iteratively scans the caller's parents and returns the filename of first 
    encounter with a function coming from outside the __packages__ folder.
    """
    start_depth = 2
    for depth in range(start_depth,len(inspect.stack())):
        fullpath = inspect.stack()[depth][1]
        if not "__packages__" in fullpath:
            return fullpath
    return "unknown"
```

It happends that when calling this from the `jupyter_notebook.ipynb` (through some other functions for example in `a_worker_module.py` in the example above), the output is :

```py
filename = "<ipython-input-5-85f02d5afdeb>"
```

whereas it works fine for `control_test.py` file in `somefolder`

```py
filename = "root/some_folder/control_test.py"
```

Do you know how inspect or (any other method for that matter) could access the jupyter lab notebook real file name and not the kernel instance, so to get the correct path : `root/some_folder/jupyter_notebook.ipynb` ?

Comment: While you might be able to extract the filename from some Jupyter specific place, please be aware that your assumption that an object/function can generally be traced to an actual file is just not correct.

Comment: Ah, okay. What's the limiting factor here ? I thought that the highly dynamic nature of the python scripting language allowed an almost transparent access from parent to child "metadata" up to infinity and beyond.